# Moving specific elements of an array from one array to another of different size

Tags: java, arrays

I was asked to

> Create a method with a single parameter, an array of integers, that will return an array of integers. Count how many odd values exists within the array. Create a new array with that many elements.  Place all the odd values into this new array ( that is all odd values from the array passed through as a parameter ).  Return this new array

but I am having some difficulty in transferring the odd values into the new array. I can get the correct size based on the number of odd values in the first array but right now they appear as zeros. Here is the code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static int output(int[]beans){
        int sum = 0;
        for (int p = 0; p < beans.length; p++){
            if(beans[p]%2 != 0){
                sum++;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("The number of odd vaules in this array are: "+sum);
        System.out.println();
        int[] notbeans = new int[sum];
        System.out.print("The odd values within the first array are: ");
        for (int index = 0; index < beans.length; index++){
            if( beans [index] %2 != 0){
                System.out.print(beans[index]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int g = 0; g < notbeans.length; g++){
            System.out.print(notbeans[g]);
        }
        return notbeans[1];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[]array = new int[5];
        for (int t = 0; t < array.length; t++){
            System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
            array[t] = key.nextInt();
        }
        output(array);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question gives me the impression that it is a homework assignment and as such you probably have limitations in how to solve it. It can be solved quite easily using the [stream API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2.html). Is using the stream API allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your question, method `output` needs to...

> Return this new array

Hence method `output` needs to return `int[]` (and **not** `int`).

After counting the number of odd values in the array passed to method `output` and creating the array that the method needs to return, in order to populate the returned array, you need to maintain a second [array] index. You are using the same index to populate the returned array and to iterate the array parameter. The returned array may be smaller in size, i.e. contain less elements, than the array parameter so using the same index for both arrays may cause method `output` to throw [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html). In any method, you should also always check whether the method parameters are valid.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static int[] output(int[] beans) {
        int sum = 0;
        if (beans != null  &&  beans.length > 0) {
            for (int p = 0; p < beans.length; p++) {
                if (beans[p] % 2 == 1) {
                    sum++;
                }
            }
        }
        int[] notBeans = new int[sum];
        int j = 0;
        for (int index = 0; index < beans.length; index++) {
            if (beans[index] % 2 == 1) {
                notBeans[j++] = beans[index];
            }
        }
        return notBeans;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] array = new int[5];
        for (int t = 0; t < array.length; t++){
            System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
            array[t] = key.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output(array)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your output function should return an array, so return type will not be `int`. It will be `int[]`. See the below code and let me know.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[]array = new int[5];
        for (int t = 0; t < array.length; t++){
            System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
            array[t] = key.nextInt();
        }
        int[] arr=output(array);
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            int val=arr[i];
            if(val!=0){
                System.out.println(val);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static int[] output(int[]beans){
        int[] notBeans=new int[beans.length];
        int i=0;
        for(int v:beans){
            if(v%2!=0){
                notBeans[i]=v;
                i++;
            }
        }
        return notBeans;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't realize I overlooked the return type, thank you for the help